# Beamer presentation with Palatino font looks different from thesis

Tags: beamer, fonts

In my thesis I used the Palatino font in the whole document (specifically the [mathpazo](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo) package), therefore I would like to use the same font in a presentation that I'm preparing. The problem is that when I set `\usepackage{mathpazo}`, the font that comes out in the presentation doesn't look the same as the font in the thesis. Below is an example of what my thesis looks like:

[image: Thesis example]

When I use this MWE beamer presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{palatino}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Info}
        Various ways that AM could help to develop the space industry:
        {\footnotesize \begin{itemize}
                \item Printing of components and replacements
                \item Recycling of materials
                \item Creation of structures that are hard to produce on Earth or difficult to transport to orbit
                \item ISRU
                \item The creation of new materials and parts that may one day be made in microgravity only and may only function there, i.e. they would be truly space based
        \begin{equation}
        F=kx
        \end{equation}
        \end{itemize}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image: Presentation example]

The fonts in the two documents are not the same even though I use the same package. What is the reason for this? I tried adding the package `palatino` but again the fonts don't look the same.

Comment: You also need to run `\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}`, after loading the font packages. By the way, there's no need to delete the `palatino` package, as the `mathpazo` package provides both a text font and a math Palatino-type font.

Comment: You wrote, "In my thesis I used the Palatino font in the whole document ..., therefore I would like to use the same font in a presentation that I'm preparing." Unless the folks in the audience are somehow pre-disposed to expect to see the Palatino font used in your presentation (possibly because they're the readers of your thesis?), your claim contains a non-sequitur. To wit, a font that's suitable for printed documents need not be optimal for presentations. If you want to give your presentation a slightly non-standard "look", consider using the `arev` text and math font package.

Comment: Using `\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}` and the `mathpazo` package unfortunately only changes the font of the text, not the maths. Also, let me clarify, I want to use Palatino because I have a lot of images that were formatted for the thesis and I don't want to have to re-format them again.

Comment: To enable the math-font part of `mathpazo`, run `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` before loading `mathpazo`. See also p. 196 of `beamer`'s user guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable the use of Palatino in both text and math mode, I suggest you add the instructions `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` and `\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\mode<presentation> {%
    \usetheme{Copenhagen}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamersize{text margin left= 5mm,
                   text margin right=5mm}
}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % or: {newpxtext,newpxmath}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Info}
Various ways that AM could help to develop the space industry:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Printing of components and replacements
    \item The creation of new materials and parts that may one day be 
          made in microgravity only and may only function there, i.e., 
          they would be truly space based
    \begin{equation}
        F=kx
    \end{equation}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```